How to Ensure Specific Order of Categorical Variables in Matplotlib Errorbar Plot (Y-axis)
I'm trying to create an error bar plot using Matplotlib, where I need to ensure a specific order of categorical variables on the y-axis. Despite setting the order of the categories and sorting the DataFrame, the plot does not reflect the desired order.
Here’s a simplified version of my code:
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Data for ITT
itt_data = {
'Variable': ['Most Similar', 'Moderately Similar', 'Distinct', 'Most Distinct'],
'Coef.': [0.2572047, 0.1326441, 0.4539544, -0.7915292],
'Std. Err.': [0.3592403, 0.3272935, 0.3179865, 0.3443217],
'0.025': [-0.4471788, -0.5090995, -0.1695404, -1.466661],
'0.975': [0.9615881, 0.7743876, 1.077449, -0.1163975]
}
itt_df = pd.DataFrame(itt_data)

# Set the order of the 'Variable' column
order = ['Most Similar', 'Moderately Similar', 'Distinct', 'Most Distinct']
itt_df['Variable'] = pd.Categorical(itt_df['Variable'], categories=order, ordered=True)
itt_df = itt_df.sort_values('Variable')

# Plotting function for ITT
def plot_itt_coefficients(data, title, color, filename):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 8))  # Different size for ITT plot

    # Reorder the data according to the specified order
    data = data.set_index('Variable').reindex(order)
    
    # Ensure the variables are plotted in the correct order
    variables = data.index.tolist()
    coefficients = data['Coef.'].tolist()
    errors_low = (data['Coef.'] - data['0.025']).tolist()
    errors_high = (data['0.975'] - data['Coef.']).tolist()
    errors = [errors_low, errors_high]
    
    ax.errorbar(coefficients, range(len(variables)), xerr=errors, fmt='o', capsize=3, elinewidth=1.5, color=color)
    ax.axvline(x=0, color='black', linestyle='--')
    ax.set_xlim(-3, 3)
    ax.set_yticks(range(len(variables)))
    ax.set_yticklabels(variables)
    ax.set_xlabel('Point Estimate')
    ax.set_ylabel('')
    ax.set_title(title)
    
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig(filename)  # Save the figure
    plt.show()

# Colors from the screenshot
colors = ['#b5d1ae', '#80ae9a', '#568b87', '#326b77', '#1b485e', '#122740']

# Plot ITT Results
plot_itt_coefficients(itt_df, 'ITT', colors[0], 'ITT_Results.png')


Your code produces this plot/y-order, which matches the categories, no ?

Yes, but the order in which the categories are presented on the Y-axis is not as I wanted. Instead of presenting 'Most Similar', 'Moderately Similar', 'Distinct', and then 'Most Distinct' - the categories are ordered the other way around, meaning 'Most Distinct', 'Distinct', 'Moderately Similar', Most Similar'.

IOW you want "Most Distinct" at the bottom, don't you?

You need to reverse all of your data data['x'] = data['x'][::-1]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import array

d = {k:array(v[::-1]) for k, v in
        {'Variable': ['Most Similar', 'Moderately Similar', 'Distinct', 'Most Distinct'],
         'Coef.': [0.2572047, 0.1326441, 0.4539544, -0.7915292],
         'Std. Err.': [0.3592403, 0.3272935, 0.3179865, 0.3443217],
         '0.025': [-0.4471788, -0.5090995, -0.1695404, -1.466661],
         '0.975': [0.9615881, 0.7743876, 1.077449, -0.1163975]}.items()
    }

xerr = array((d['Coef.']-d['0.025'], d['0.975']-d['Coef.']))
plt.errorbar(d['Coef.'], d['Variable'], xerr=xerr, fmt='o')
plt.axvline(x=0, color='black', linestyle='--')
plt.xlim((-3, +3))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()


Great! It works. Thank you!
